# Why is this loop variables always 0?

Tags: objective-c

Why is this loop giving me always 0 ( columns and rows has a value = 0 always )? there's any mistake? I can't find it!

```
- (void)drawView:(UIView *)theView
{

    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    for (int columns = 0; columns < 6; columns++) 
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < 2; rows++) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Drawing  n%f: { rows: %f }, { columns: %f }, { x: %f }, { y: %f }, { z: %f }", rows, columns, columns * rows);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "giving"? Could you try to be precise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%d` instead of `%f` to print integers.